# Python newbie: Printing a list with values from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

How to print the output of this list with values from the dictionary?

`dict = [{"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"}]
list = ['1', '2']
[dict[k] for k in list]`

How to pass dict[k] to another list and to print it?

Comment: 1. Your `dict` is actually a `list`, otherwise this code is functionally correct (once removing the brackets either side)

2. You should not use `list` or `dict` as variable names, as these are reserved keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `dict` is not dict because you made it as `list`.
So, I added `[0]` to index from `list`.

```
my_dict = [{"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"}]
my_list = ['1', '2']
result = [my_dict[0][k] for k in my_list]

print (result)
```

The result is:

```
['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Please don't reinforce the use of reserved keywords as variables names.. Don't use `dict` or `list` like that.

Comment: @Nordle I just reuse the snippet code of OP. OP could understand well. But, I agree with you. We need to provide good sample code as the answer of stackoverflow. By the way, Please cancel the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Please allow me to add a method that should ensure that no illegal keys are used.

```
my_dict = [{"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"}]
my_list = ["1", "2", "It'sATrap!"]

dict_only = my_dict[0]  # Counting from zero makes the dict the first/zero-st list item

new_list = [dict_only[k] for k in my_list if k in dict_only.keys()]
```

`dict_only.keys()` provides you with an iterable object which has all keys of the current dictionary "layer". If one of the items in the dictionary is another dictionary, you won't get these keys as well.

*One more thing:*

Be careful with your variable names. They are shadowing inbuilt functions of python (namely, `list` and `dict` are both keywords). To see what I refer to, try this:

```
>>> list("chicken")
['c', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n']

>>> list = "chicken"
>>> list("chicken")
```

which will result in a TypeError, as your string `list` is not callable!